# Finding a number that is both a prime number and a palindrome

Tags: integer, compare, output, palindrome

I' fairly new to java. I have code in which a use inputs a number and the program check every number from 1 to n and outputs every number that is both a prime number and a palindrome. However my code doesn't output anything for some reason. There are no errors in the code, so I'm not sure what's wrong exactly. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab5 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)  {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a value:");  //Asking the user to input     the value n
        int n =scanner.nextInt();
        for (int y=2; y<=n; y++) { //For every number from 2 to n
            prime(y);                     //the prime number is checked
            pal(y);                         //and so is the palindrome
            if ((prime(y)==true) && (pal(y)==true)) { //if a number is both a prime AND a palindrome (both methods are being compared here)
                System.out.println(y);                          //it is printed out
            }
    }
    }
    public static boolean prime(int n) { //the method for finding the prime number
        int x = 2;
        while (n%x>0) {
        x+=1;
        } if (x==n) {
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

public static boolean pal(int n) { //the method for finding a palindrome
    int rev = 0;
    int rmd = 0;
    while (n>0) {
        rmd = n%10;
        rev = rev*10 + rmd;
        n = n/10;
    } if (rev==n) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) will help you

Comment: for no 23, what should be output?

Answer (score 0):

Your palindrome method is returning wrong result. 
You are modifying `n` and after then comparing with reversed number.

First save that value then compare after while loop

```
int number = n;
If(rev == number)  return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking in your `pal()` function. Your n variable is getting 0 and you are comparing it to reverse no.

Assign that variable to a `temp` variable and then compare. I made some changes to your code and it working great.

```
import java.util.*;
public class A 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)  {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a value:");  //Asking the user to input     the value n
        int n =scanner.nextInt();
        for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
            if (prime(i) && pal(i)) { //if a number is both a prime AND a palindrome (both methods are being compared here)
                System.out.println(i);                          //it is printed out
            }
        }
    }
    public static boolean prime(int n) { //the method for finding the prime number
        int x = 2;
        while (n%x>0) {
            x+=1;
        } if (x==n) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static boolean pal(int n) { //the method for finding a palindrome
        int rev = 0;
            int rmd = 0;
        int temp = n;
            while (n>0) {
                rmd = n%10;
                rev = rev*10 + rmd;
                n = n/10;
            }
        if (rev==temp){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]